# Ssl certificate on a tcp load balancer?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I was wondering if an ssl certificate can be added to a tcp load balancer or does this require an http load balancer?

I do this through google cloud platform.

Comment: The TCP load balancer does not support SSL certificates. See this link for SSL Proxy Load Balancer: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl#ssl_certificates

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs), Google managed and Self signed SSL certificates are not supported for TCP/UDP Load balancer.

As a workaround for testing purpose, you can follow the below steps :

1. With service type as “Load balancer”, try to install the 3rd party SSL certificate in the backend “evserver” pod itself with port 443 and check whether you were able to access it without certification error.
2. Another method is to try to use the service as type “Nodeport” instead of service with type “Load balancer'' and check whether you were able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TCP proxy load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl) when you are dealing with TCP traffic and do not need SSL offload.

Use [SSL proxy load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl) when you are dealing with TCP traffic and need SSL offload.

If you are still not sure about what Load Balancer to choose, please read through this helpful [document](https://medium.com/google-cloud/choosing-the-right-load-balancer-9ec909148a85) to know more about different Load Balancer types and their appropriate use case.